# How to embed a NOT Downloable PDF in your website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, pdf

I want to embed a PDF in my PHP based website. The Content in my PDF is unique and written by me and i want my web site viewers to view and read content but i dont want them download those pdf file.

Can can one help me out???

Comment: If it can't be downloaded, then software on the viewer's computer can't display it.

Comment: The user would need some plugin extension in order for you to embed the pdf file, but it would still be downloaded as all content has to be downloaded in order for it to be viewed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's your goal, you cannot include the PDF data in the web page. In order for the browser to display the PDF, it has to be able to download it; at that point, all bets are off.

To do what you describe, you'd have to render the output in some form that isn't readily reused, such as an image, or by embedding a Flash or Java applet and having it render the text graphically. But doing that means the content can't readily be indexed by search engines.* And of course, anyone sufficiently-motivated can apply optical character recognition to get the text.

---

*(* Search engines are really smart these days, but I don't* think *they regularly apply OCR to images in hopes of finding index-able text there.)*